# visual studio ultimate 2013 run single test then code coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, test-coverage

So I created a few test methods for very simple code and when I right click and run each test separately, they all pass. Then I click "Analyze code coverage for all tests" and one of the tests is failing. Nothing has been changed in between these two actions (no save, no build, no touching of the code). What could cause this? Are there some settings that I need to be aware of?